# Error When Arranging Multiple Panels in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a card game application just for fun while I am bored over the summer. I am pretty new to JFrames so I decided to look at others code and edit it to what I want it to be. After looking at the answer on this url: [How to arrange multiple panels in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067894/how-to-arrange-multiple-panels-in-jframe?newreg=821095d9d70d4169802cc917391b3f32), I tried to replicate it to my needs. The issue is that when I run the program nothing shows up other than the title of the base JFrame but no functionality (such as selecting to see players hand). I cant seem to find the reason why none of the functionality is showing up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PlayGame extends JFrame {

    private static void createAndShowUI(){
        HandGui gui = new HandGui();
        HandMenu menu = new HandMenu(gui);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hands of Players");
        frame.getContentPane().add(gui.getMainPanel());
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu.getJMenuBar());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run(){
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private PlayGame(){

    }
}
class HandGui {
    private static final String[][] PLAYER1_BIN_TEXTS = {
        {"Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3" , "Card 4"}, {"Card 5", "Card 6", "Card 7", "Card 8"},
        {"Card 9", "Card 10", "Card 11" , "Card 12"}, {"Card 13"}};
    private static final String[][] PLAYER2_BIN_TEXTS  = {
        {"Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3" , "Card 4"}, {"Card 5", "Card 6", "Card 7", "Card 8"},
        {"Card 9", "Card 10", "Card 11" , "Card 12"}, {"Card 13"}}; 
    private static final String[][] PLAYER3_BIN_TEXTS  = {
        {"Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3" , "Card 4"}, {"Card 5", "Card 6", "Card 7", "Card 8"},
        {"Card 9", "Card 10", "Card 11" , "Card 12"}, {"Card 13"}}; 
    private static final String[][] PLAYER4_BIN_TEXTS  = {
        {"Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3" , "Card 4"}, {"Card 5", "Card 6", "Card 7", "Card 8"},
        {"Card 9", "Card 10", "Card 11" , "Card 12"}, {"Card 13"}};

    private static final int GAP = 5;//
    private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 20);

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel p1Panel;
    private JPanel p2Panel;
    private JPanel p3Panel;
    private JPanel p4Panel;

    private JTextField display = new JTextField();//May not need

    HandGui() {
        display.setFont(BTN_FONT);
        p1Panel = createBtnPanel(PLAYER1_BIN_TEXTS, "Player 1 Hand");
        p2Panel = createBtnPanel(PLAYER2_BIN_TEXTS, "Player 2 Hand");
        p3Panel = createBtnPanel(PLAYER3_BIN_TEXTS, "Player 3 Hand");
        p4Panel = createBtnPanel(PLAYER4_BIN_TEXTS, "Player 4 Hand");

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.add(p1Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(p2Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(p3Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(p4Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p1Panel.setVisible(true);
        p2Panel.setVisible(false);
        p3Panel.setVisible(false);
        p4Panel.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void p1PanelSetVisable(boolean visable) {
        p1Panel.setVisible(true);
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        win.pack();
    }

    public void p2PanelSetVisable(boolean visable) {
        p2Panel.setVisible(true);
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        win.pack();
    }

    public void p3PanelSetVisable(boolean visable) {
        p3Panel.setVisible(true);
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        win.pack();
    }

    public void p4PanelSetVisable(boolean visable) {
        p4Panel.setVisible(true);
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        win.pack();
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createBtnPanel(String[][] texts, String title){
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        int rows = texts.length;
        int cols = texts[0].length;
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));

        for(int row = 0; row < texts.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < texts[row].length; col++){
                JButton btn = new JButton(texts[row][col]);
                btn.setFont(BTN_FONT);
                btnPanel.add(btn);
            }
        }
        btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return btnPanel;
            }
    }

class HandMenu {
    private static final String PLAYER1 = "Player 1";
    private static final String PLAYER2 = "Player 2";
    private static final String PLAYER3 = "Player 3";
    private static final String PLAYER4 = "Player 4";
    private HandGui gui;
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenuItem p1Hand;
    private JMenuItem p2Hand;
    private JMenuItem p3Hand;
    private JMenuItem p4Hand;

    HandMenu(HandGui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        p1Hand = new JMenuItem(PLAYER1, KeyEvent.VK_1);
        p2Hand = new JMenuItem(PLAYER2, KeyEvent.VK_2);
        p3Hand = new JMenuItem(PLAYER3, KeyEvent.VK_3);
        p4Hand = new JMenuItem(PLAYER4, KeyEvent.VK_4);
        ViewAction viewAction = new ViewAction();
        p1Hand.addActionListener(viewAction);
        p2Hand.addActionListener(viewAction);
        p3Hand.addActionListener(viewAction);
        p4Hand.addActionListener(viewAction);
        p1Hand.setEnabled(false);
        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("Change Players");
        viewMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        viewMenu.add(p1Hand);
        viewMenu.add(p2Hand);
        viewMenu.add(p3Hand);
        viewMenu.add(p4Hand);
    }

    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar(){
        return menuBar;
    }

    private class ViewAction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if(command.equals(PLAYER1)){
                gui.p1PanelSetVisable(true);
                gui.p2PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p3PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p4PanelSetVisable(false);
                p1Hand.setEnabled(false);
                p2Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p3Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p4Hand.setEnabled(true);
            } else if(command.equals(PLAYER2)){
                gui.p1PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p2PanelSetVisable(true);
                gui.p3PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p4PanelSetVisable(false);
                p1Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p2Hand.setEnabled(false);
                p3Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p4Hand.setEnabled(true);
            } else if(command.equals(PLAYER3)){
                gui.p1PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p2PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p3PanelSetVisable(true);
                gui.p4PanelSetVisable(false);
                p1Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p2Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p3Hand.setEnabled(false);
                p4Hand.setEnabled(true);
            } else if(command.equals(PLAYER4)){
                gui.p1PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p2PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p3PanelSetVisable(false);
                gui.p4PanelSetVisable(true);
                p1Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p2Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p3Hand.setEnabled(true);
                p4Hand.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time posting on stack overflow so I am sorry if I did not clarify my problem correctly.

Comment: To make window larger you need to set size of the frame - `frame.setSize(500,500);`

Comment: @NinadPingale Or just let `pack` deal with it, which the OP is doing, which takes into consideration cross platform frame decorations, the problem is deeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BorderLayout` only allows a single component to occupy a given position, so...

```
mainPanel.add(p1Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(p2Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(p3Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(p4Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Means that only `p4Panel` will be shown...

For switching between panels, you are better of using `CardLayout` instead of...

```
p1Panel.setVisible(true);
p2Panel.setVisible(false);
p3Panel.setVisible(false);
p4Panel.setVisible(false);
```

This is why you frame is blank, because `p4Panel` is invisible, but it is the only component that `BorderLayout` will try to layout...

Now, essentially as near as I can tell, nothing in `HandMenu` is getting applied to any UI components (none of the menus are been set)...

You need to be adding your `JMenu` to the `menuBar`, for example...

```
menuBar.add(viewMenu);
```

Instead of looking at other peoples example, I would suggest checking out:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)
- [How to use `CardLayout`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add more than one component to the center of the panel

```
    mainPanel.add(p1Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(p2Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(p3Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(p4Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p1Panel.setVisible(true);
    p2Panel.setVisible(false);
    p3Panel.setVisible(false);
    p4Panel.setVisible(false);
```

To do what you want you need a proxy panel with a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

```
    JPanel proxyPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    proxyPanel.add(p1Panel, "0");        
    proxyPanel.add(p1Panel, "1");
    proxyPanel.add(p1Panel, "2");
    proxyPanel.add(p1Panel, "3");
    mainPanel.add(proxyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Do not use `setVisible(boolean)`. To make panel with index 1 visible use `CardLayout.show(mainPanel, "1")`.